# How to apply regex over entire dataframe without making all columns to character

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I needed to remove "Z" from dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Mineral = c("Zfeldspar", "Zgranite", "ZSilica"),
                Confidence = c("ZLow", "High", "Med"),
                Coverage = c("sub", "sub", "super"),
                Aspect = c("ZPos", "ZUnd", "Neg"),
                Pile1 = c(70, 88, 95),
                Pile2 = c(62,41,81))
```

I used tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mutate_all(df, funs(str_replace_all(., "Z", ""))) %>%
      mutate(PileAvg = mean(Pile1 + Pile2))
```

But I get error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

I did investigating and this is because Pile columns are character now, not numbers. How do I use regex to remove "Z" without changing everything? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `df` creation, you didn't set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so your character columns will automatically be coerced to factors.  If you set this to `TRUE` or use `tibble` or `data_frame` you'll get character colunns.

This is where you'd use `mutate_if` rather than `mutate_all`.  Here's an approach that will work for both factors and characters, by constructing a predicate function to use in `mutate_if`.

```
df <- data.frame(Mineral = c("Zfeldspar", "Zgranite", "ZSilica"),
                 Confidence = c("ZLow", "High", "Med"),
                 Coverage = c("sub", "sub", "super"),
                 Aspect = c("ZPos", "ZUnd", "Neg"),
                 Pile1 = c(70, 88, 95),
                 Pile2 = c(62,41,81))

is_character_factor <- function(x){

  is.character(x)|is.factor(x)

}

mutate_if(df, is_character_factor, funs(str_replace(., "Z", ""))) %>%
  mutate(PileAvg = mean(Pile1 + Pile2))
```

Comment: could also do: `mutate_if(df,~ !is.numeric(.), funs(str_replace_all(., "Z", ""))) %>% mutate(PileAvg = mean(Pile1 + Pile2))`

Comment: @rockhound it's due to `stringsAsFactors`, see my response

Comment: oh thank you! I see now! so I use tibble() instead of dataframe

Answer (score 1):

@Jake Kaupps' answer is excellent, but here's another way of doing it using `modify_if` from `purrr`.

I also noticed that it looks like you are trying to compute row means, in which case using `means(Pile1 + Pile2)` will not work. You can compute the means row-wise by calling your original dataframe using `rowwise()`.

```
df <- modify_if(rowwise(df), is.character, function (x) str_replace_all(x, "Z", "")) %>%
      mutate(PileAvg = mean(c(Pile1,Pile2)))

# Output
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Mineral  Confidence Coverage Aspect Pile1 Pile2 PileAvg
  <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 feldspar Low        sub      Pos      70.   62.    66.0
2 granite  High       sub      Und      88.   41.    64.5
3 Silica   Med        super    Neg      95.   81.    88.0
```

`modify_if()` is slightly more efficient time-wise, but for your purposes I'd stick with Jake's answer.